# How to disable Plural suffix?

Tags: strapi

**Collection Types List**  does not list **collectionName**

API name is not "collection name" instead it is "Display Name" of Created collection type.

### How to control Plural suffix?

#### Is there any way to define new irregular rule for pluralize utility?

`pluralize.plural('irregular') //=> "irregulars"`

I can not create content types other than English. It just adds it's own suffix, it makes i18n impossible.

**Steps to reproduce the behavior**

1. Go to 'Content-Types Builder'
2. Click on 'Create new collection type'
3. Enter "araba" (a non-english word) to 'Display name'
4. Enter "arabalar" (plural non-english word) to 'Collection name' under 'Advanced Settings'
5. Check out left menu it does not display **collectionName** instead it displays API name

**Expected behavior**

IT SHOULD BE "arabalar" not "arabas" which was entered as **collection name**

**Screenshots**

[image: singular]
[image: plural]

#### "arabalar" is plural of "araba" not "arabas"

[image: wrong]

**System**

- Node.js version: v12.16.1
- yarn version: 1.22.4
- Strapi version: v3.0.0-beta.19.3
- Database: sqlite
- Operating system: windows

Comment: I think there is no simple solution to disable pluralization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to disable pluralization, but there is a workaround:

1. Open file api\araba\models\araba.settings.json (araba is your API name)
2. Add key displayName to info part of the

```js
    "info": {
       "name": "Araba",
       "displayName": "arabalar"
     },
```

4. create a file admin/src/components/LeftMenuLinkSection/index.js
5. copy into it the contents of file node_modules/strapi-admin/admin/src/components/LeftMenuLinkSection/index.js
6. Change this

```js
   <LeftMenuLink
     location={location}
     key={index}
     iconName={link.icon}
     label={link.label}
     destination={getLinkDestination(link)}
   />
```

to this

```js
       <LeftMenuLink
         location={location}
         key={index}
         iconName={link.icon}
         label={link.schema && link.schema.info.displayName ? link.schema.info.displayName : link.label}
         destination={getLinkDestination(link)}
        />
```

and `yarn strapi build`

Comment: That works, thanks! I have a question about admin panel. I customizing admin panel in node_modules. I felt this is not best practice.  Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can copy any file from /node_modules/strapi-admin/admin/src/ to /admin/src/ and make changes there. Don't customize this files in node_modules.

Comment: I don't think this is possible anymore in v3.x, I did the changes you suggested and nothing changes. I did look into it and these are the 'link' object properties: {
destination: "/plugins/content-manager/collectionType/application::slider-inicio.slider-inicio",
icon: "circle",
isDisplayed: true,
label: "SliderInicios"...]
The 'schema' property is not there.

Comment: Here you can see how to do it for the new version, it's pretty much the same thing but in other place: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/6332

Answer (score 4):

The correct (and simplest) solution IMHO can be found in this Strapi issue: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/8915#issuecomment-748436263. I'll simply report it:

> I actually just figured out a more simple way to solve this issue.
>
> I looked trough the code and found that this package:
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/pluralize is used for the pluralization.
> It has a build in method to add new rules. So what I did, is that I
> added the word/words from my local language (danish), which are
> getting translated wrong in this file: `/config/functions/bootstrap.js`
> which is executed before the app starts.
>
> Like this:
>
> ```js
> 'use strict';
>
> const pluralize = require('pluralize')
>
> /**
>  * An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before
>  * your application gets started.
>  *
>  * This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model,
>  * run jobs, or perform some special logic.
>  *
>  * See more details here: https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#bootstrap
>  */
>
> module.exports = () => {
>     // Add danish plural versions of collection names
>     pluralize.addPluralRule('side', 'sider')
>     pluralize.addPluralRule('aktivitet', 'aktiviteter')  };
> ```
>
> And then just let the server restart.

Comment: Thanks for that! I got it to work in Strapi 3.6.1. Just one thing I can add here: The name that you define in each collection JSON like:

"info": {
    "name": "Werk",
    "description": ""
 },

must be the singular version to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to disable pluralization in Strapi.

Answer (score 0):

the solution described above does not work in strapi version 3. In version 3.x you have to do it like this:

1. extends your Model with "displayName", open the file api\{model}\models\{model}.settings.json and add a new attribute

   ```
   "info": { "name": "xy", "displayName": "Display Name" }
   ```
2. create a new file under **admin\src\containers\LeftMenu\utils\generateModelsLinks.js** (copy&paste the original file from **node_modules\strapi-admin\admin\src\containers\LeftMenu\utils**)
3. change the line (11) from

   ```
   label: link.info.label
   ```

   to

   ```
   label: link.info && link.info.displayName ? link.info.displayName
   ```